# How to store docx file in assets folder to device public directory on android device e.g. "Downloads"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to save files from the asset folder to the android device's public directory e.g. "Downloads".
Normal file read-write doesn't seem to work.
How to do it?

I have tried this 
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)
but  this didn't work.

```
fun copy() {
val bufferSize = 1024
val assetManager = context.assets
val assetFiles = assetManager.list("")

assetFiles.forEach {
    val inputStream = assetManager.open(it)
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), it))

    try {
        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream, bufferSize)
    } finally {
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: add your code in post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What API level are you trying to run this on? As file access is changing a lot in API level 29 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled runtime read/write permissions and after that simply you can use this code to save any file to a directory.

```
fun saveImageToExternalStorage(image:Bitmap) {
  val fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/downloads"
  try
  {
    val dir = File(fullPath)
    if (!dir.exists())
    {
      dir.mkdirs()
    }
    val fOut:OutputStream = null
    val file = File(fullPath, "image.png")
    if (file.exists())
    file.delete()
    file.createNewFile()
    fOut = FileOutputStream(file)
    // 100 means no compression, the lower you go, the stronger the compression
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut)
    fOut.flush()
    fOut.close()
  }
  catch (e:Exception) {
    Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: `you can use this code to save any file to a directory.` Any file? You are saving a bitmap only. Not even one file. And not from assets.

Comment: @blackapps due that's a common sense to replace bitmap with your file i'm just giving you the logic to save to a directory do the rest on your own!